# ProvisionException: Unable to provision

Tags: scala, playframework, slick-3.0

I got this error while trying to integrate postgresql into my play app:

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors: 
1) No implementation for play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider was bound. 
while locating play.api.db.slick.DatabaseConfigProvider 
for parameter 0 at models.EntryRepo.<init>(EntryRepo.scala:10) 
while locating models.EntryRepo 
for parameter 0 at controllers.Entries.<init>(Entries.scala:17) 
while locating controllers.Entries for parameter 4 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:39) 
while locating router.Routes 
while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider while locating play.api.routing.Router
```

My SBT file:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    cache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.1.1",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
    "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.1.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

My application.conf

```
slicks.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slicks.dbs.default.dataSourceClass="slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/aleksander"
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.user = postgres
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.password = "lelelel"
```

The parts with the injection

```
class EntryRepo @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {...}
class Entries @Inject()(entryRepo: EntryRepo) extends Controller {...}
```

I've been following the play-slick3 template from activator. I tried to follow the template as close as possible but the error still persists

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue and I was using Play 2.5.x.

In their new **application.conf** their code convention has changed from simple toggling to more "JSONish" formatting (called **HOCON**).

```
db {
foo
}
```

And you may be tricked into thinking that you should put

```
slicks.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slicks.dbs.default.dataSourceClass="slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.url ="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/aleksander"
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.user = postgres
slicks.dbs.default.db.default.password = "lelelel"
```

inside those `db {}` braces. However, after pulling my hairs for over 6 hours I found out that putting db configuration code **OUTSIDE** those braces solves my problem. You may have fallen into similiar trap.

Of course you can use this in jsonic fashion like this:

```
slicks.dbs.default.db { /* your slick configuration */}
```